# Why not repurpose mapping as array in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping

An array T[] can be implemented as a mapping(uint -> T)  with indices acting as key in mapping and storing array length as separate uint.
I want to understand, if it is more gas efficient to use arrays than (mapping+ uint) for any operation, be it inserting, random access or iterating?

Cannot find anything conclusive on this in docs.

Comment: An excellent question! Haven't thought of using mappings like that. But don't have an answer for you.